# When I try to click one radio button it selects the other

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, when I click the 'Submit' button and I have the 'no' radio button selected it selects the 'yes' radio button..

Script:

```
    function action() {
        var name = document.getElementById('username').value;
        document.getElementById("theIMG").src = "https://crafatar.com/avatars/" + name;
        console.log("Working");

        if (document.getElementById('render_Yes').checked = true) {
            document.getElementById("renderIMG").src = "https://crafatar.com/renders/body/" + name + "?helm&scale=4";
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById('render_No').checked = true) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
Render: <br/>
<input type="radio" name="yn" id="render_Yes" value="yes">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="yn" id="render_No" value="no" checked="checked">No</input> <br/> <br/>

<button id="submit" onClick="action()">Submit</button> <br />
<br />
<img id="theIMG"></img>
<img id="renderIMG"></img>
```

Comment: Your HTML markup is not really correct - `<input>` elements have no content, and so there's no need for `</input>`. Same goes for `<img>` - no closing tag is needed.

Comment: Ah.. Ok, thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `if` statements:

```
    if (document.getElementById('render_Yes').checked = true) {
```

You're trying to *compare* to `true`, but instead you're *setting* the property to `true`. The `=` operator is for assignment; you're looking for the `==` or `===` operators, though in this case you really just need to check the property as a boolean:

```
    if (document.getElementById('render_Yes').checked) {
```